# Any way to set autocomplete for all future Pull request to a particular Branch say master

Tags: azure, azure-devops, pull-request

Is there a way for all future pull requests to be auto-completed once all branch policies have successfully passed? Can we set this on a branch level (e.g. all PR's targeting master), instead of doing this manually for every new PR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any way to set autocomplete for all future Pull request to a particular Branch say master

I am afraid there is no such a way to set autocomplete for all future Pull request to a particular Branch at this moment.

Many community members have submit the same request in our main suggestion forum:

[Option to allow Auto-Complete to be the default option on new pull-requests](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365686/option-to-allow-auto-complete-to-be-the-default-op.html)

You could vote and add your comments for this feedback.